# Docker automated build from private bitbucket repo: Failed to clone repository

Tags: docker, bitbucket, private, dockerfile

I want to add some automated builds for my docker containers, so I linked my bitbucket account with docker. Then I created an automated build and choose a private bitbucket repo.

If I now trigger a build the build failed with the following error message:

> Failed to clone repository: Cloning into
>   '/tmp/build_xxxx'... Warning: Permanently added the
>   RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.xxx' to the list of known
>   hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

For public repos the build works without any problems.

Any ideas why private repos are not working?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the rsa public key of the user in your Docker container that you are using to connect to [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org)

[image: Bitbucket]

Generally the public key is under:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

or you can generate one:

```
user@host $ ssh-keygen
```

then commit your docker container to create a new image:

```
docker commit <container-id> mycontainer:0.1
```

Comment: I don't unterstand. I already have a ssh key in bitbucket, but this is the key from my host. If I add a new key, how does bitbucket know that this key is for an automated build from docker hub?

Comment: @mc388 you are pulling the git repo from your Docker container not from your host.

Comment: My containers are not running at this moment. There is only a private bitbucket repo within a Dockerfile, which is connected to an automated build repo on docker hub. My docker account has access to bitbucket with an OAuth connection.

Comment: you can copy the private key from your host to your container at build time. Make sure you copy it to the the user directory that you are using to connect to github  `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: ok I understand but this sounds not like a best practice solution but I will try it on monday. It's time for weekend ;)

Comment: @mc388 try manually instantiating your container running /bin/bash and then doing the `git pull` from there. Something is wrong with your keys/user